# process.env returning undefined but not in console

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have tried solution from other questions but still the same.
process.env keep returning undefined but it does return the value in console

```js
console.log(process.env.SSECRET) //return the value
App.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SSECRET //return undefined
  ...
});
```

I'm using express with typescript, I defined the dotenv at the very top main file like this:

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname.replace("/src", "")+"/.env" });
```

I have tried

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname.replace("/src", "")+"/.env" })
```

```js
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config({ path: __dirname.replace("/src", "")+"/.env" })
```

process.env doesn't include my env variable if I remove the path parameter.

Comment: leave `.env` in the root dir and simply do `dotenv.config({ path: ".env" });`

Comment: The guide suggests starting with `require('dotenv').config()` (which will look for .env in the current working directory `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`) then do `console.log(process.env)` to confirm it's working.